# Get child class properties in parent constructor

Tags: c#

```
class A
{
    public string PropA {set; get;}

    public A()
    {
        var props = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
    }
}


class B : A
{
    public string PropB {set; get;}
}

var b = new B();
```

When `A` constructor is called, variable `props` contains only `PropA`. It's possible to get all properties (`PropA` and `PropB`)?

Comment: Is there any specific reason this has to be in the constructor? `this` in an `A` constructor will always be of type `A`.

Comment: @BoltClock, I need to create ORM. Class B is an model (Comment, for example). Class A is the common ORM model, that define operation like Save, Add, Get and e.t. Each field in B is an field in database Table. I need to know, what field contains table to build SQL query. Maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
var props = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Parent class(where you have defined the constructor) does not know anything about its child class that's why it returns just `PropA`
If you define the constractor in the `B` class it will return both the properies

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of base class `A` is run *before* the constructor of the derived class `B`, so you can not access the properties of the derived class.

BTW: This doens't make sense to me, that a base class has knowledge of the derived classes!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
class A
{
    public string PropA {set; get;}

    public A()
    {
    }

    protected virtual PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
    } 
}


class B : A
{
    public string PropB {set; get;}

    public B() : base()
    {
    }

    public new PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
    }
}

var b = new B();
var prop = b.GetPropeties();
```

Answer (score 0):

A base class is not supposed to know anything about its derived classes. It breaks the Open Closed Principle and the Liskov Substitution Principle.

You solve this using generics and virtual or abstract methods. Also, don't be writing your own O/R Mapper. There are so many out there, that some must cover your needs!